# Predict angle by linear loss

Tags: nonlinear-regression, reinforcement-learning, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to solve following nonlinear regression task: We got fixed point from which the bullet is released with some start speed v0 (value v0 changes each time). On the opposite side we generate the target in random place with random width in range [0.05, 0.1]. The distance to the opposite side is 1, and the zone of target spawn is 1.

The environment affects the trajectory of the bullet according to a law, that is not known for us (for our model). This law is nonlinear, so right trajectory is nonlinear:
[image]

(green line is calculated from analytically solved equation of bullet motion with correctly calculated start angle, red line is build from angle, incorrectly predicted by model)

We predict only a start angle of bullet, but in loss function we can use only a linear measure of miss between center of target and end point of trajectory on the opposite wall. Fairly we can't calculate right angle, which leads a bullet to the center of target, the 'true Y', because the motion law is not known for us. So we predict an angle and get to loss a linear value. I made some variants of custom loss function, which returns value, calculated based on linear error, but no one of them improve accuracy, when I make validation. The result is 50-70 of 1000 tries, regardless of training time it remains nearly the same.

```
@tf.function
def custom_loss_func(a):
    if a < 0.:
        return abs(a) * 10.

    if abs(a) >= pi:
        return a * 10.

    if not (1.0472 <= a % (2 * pi) <= 2.0944):
        if 0. <= a <= 1.0472:
            return (1.0475 - a) * 2 + 5.
        else:
            return a + 5.

    # return abs(a - oracle.right_alpha)  # this works fine, but not legal


    # calculating linear value from predicted angle
    a = a * 0 - (4 * oracle.d * oracle.a) / (3 * oracle.v0 * (sin(a)+eps)) \
        + (2 * oracle.d * oracle.a) / (oracle.v0 * (sin(a)+eps)) \
        + (oracle.d * cos(a)) / (sin(a)+eps) + 0.5
    
    # does not work
    return abs(a - (oracle.x_left + (oracle.x_right - oracle.x_left) / 2))
    # return (a - (oracle.x_left + (oracle.x_right - oracle.x_left) / 2))**2


def oracle_loss():
    def custom_loss(_, y_pred):
        res = tf.map_fn(custom_loss_func, y_pred)

        return res

    return custom_loss
```

If I cheat and in loss func just return a difference between predicted and right angle (pre-calculated analytically), all works fine, of course, train works (accuracy improves to 0.75 in train dataset with size 13000).

the code of network itself:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(InputLayer(batch_input_shape=(1, oracle.param_num)))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(16, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation="linear"))

    model.compile(loss=oracle_loss(), optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-3 / 200), metrics=['mae'])


    for i in range(num_episodes):
        state = oracle.state()

        model.fit(
            x=state,
            y=np.array([[0.]]),
            epochs=1, verbose=2)
```

Hyper-parameters change also makes no difference, exactly this code works fine with "cheating" loss function.
Is there any way to use only linear error to train angle prediction network? Maybe it needs a custom nonlinear activation function for layers? Or maybe you know some examples of solving this kind of tasks?

Comment: I don't understand why it's cheating to use the correct answer to compute the loss of the network. During training, the network needs to know the correct answer to correctly compute the error, or else the model will also be learning the imprecision of the answer from `custom_loss` along with any signal. Moreover, you say that the accuracy is between 50 and 70 when using the custom loss, while the accuracy is only 75 when using the true, "cheating" loss function. So the 5% point difference seems entirely plausible as originating in the error inherent to `custom_loss`.

Comment: A loss function probably should use the true values. Otherwise, how do you know if you’ve even missed the true value? I struggle to understand why you consider that cheating. // Isn’t this kind of projectile motion solvable through the usual equations of physics? I don’t understand why this is a statistics problem.

Comment: @Dave physical equations are only known by some "black box" that only tells us a linear value of the final point of trajectory, this analytical solution is unavailable for training model, the goal is to empirically find this "unknown" function in the form of neural network weights

Comment: @Sycorax  when using the custom loss - 50 and 70 from 1000, e.g. ~0.07 without any progress , "cheating" loss function gives us 0.75. Cheating loss uses the knowledge that we honestly don't have. At the model's side we don't know the right equations, and we must repeatedly test the environment